# jstl <c:foreach error "attribute items does not accept any expressions"

Tags: jsp, jdbc, jstl, derby

Below mentiond is my **jsp** page jstl sql query:

```
 <sql:query sql="select postname,comments from root.posts"  var="rs"  dataSource="${ds}" />
                    <c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rows}">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.postname}"></c:out></td>
                            <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.comments}"></c:out></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

after executing jsp my error is :  **attribute items does not accept any expressions**
and the error cordiate shows at (28,3) which is - `<c:foreach var="row" items="${rs.rows}"..`

My **context.xml** file is:

```
 <Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/myderby" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="root" password="root"
        driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
        url="jdbc:derby:E:\workspaceDerby\DerbyNew\derbyDb;create=true"
       maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" removeAbandoned="true" />
</Context>
```

My **web.xml** file:

```
<resource-ref>
      <description>DB connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/myderby</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

Additional Info:
     
 --  using **Embedded Derby** for database inside **Eclipse-indigo**
     
 --  servlet version 3
      
-- jstl.jar version 1.2, standard.jar version 1.1.2
      
-- using **Html 5**
     
-- Took Tutorial from : [here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html)( actually tutorial is using  Server version of derby i modified it to Embedded Derby for study purpose)

--Also successfully created crud application with jsp,servlet,jstl  using MySql db but not with **Embedded Derby** (Because Embedded derby is also useful for my Standalone apps and web apps )

Comment: Can you show the taglib directive of your JSP page? It starts with `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="....`

Comment: i use <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>, which is the standard for core taglib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the URI of JSTL 1.0, which doesn't handle expression language.

Correct your JSTL URI to:

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

See the [jstl tag faq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for more information.

Comment: @EJP thank u.. for pointing out me the Error (+1 up vote); instead of  this : dataSource="${ds}" i have to point out the 'name' given in the "context.xml" so modified code is :dataSource="jdbc/myderby". heartily thanks mr ejp..

Comment: so updated jsp page code:                            <sql:setDataSource var="ds" dataSource="jdbc/myderby"/>
<sql:query sql="select postname,comments from MYSCHEMA.POSTS"  var="rs"  dataSource="${ds}" />                                             thank u all..

Comment: Useful source for jstl **DB** programming  : [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaWebDBApp.html)